# On Click/ On change item from a key of a listpreference

Tags: java, android, settings, listpreference

I am trying to make an action on a changed preference/click item from a listpreference's array.
Here is what i am doing:

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/customization_settings" >

<ListPreference android:key="selected_theme"
    android:entries="@array/themes"
    android:title="@string/themes_title"
    android:summary="@string/themes_summary"
    android:entryValues="@array/themes_values" />
</PreferenceCategory>






 <string-array name="themes">
    <item name="dark">Verde</item>
    <item name="green">Viola</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="themes_values">
    <item name="dark" translatable="false">0</item>
    <item name="green" translatable="false">1</item>
</string-array>
```

This is my list preference.
I need to set an action if the user choose an item of the array entries.
I don't know how to do it.
I searched a lot and not yet found an answer that give me a solution.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for onClick event of listpreference

```
ListPreference selected_theme = (ListPreference) getPreferenceManager().findPreference("selected_theme");
selected_theme.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
             return false;
        }
});
```

Comment: How if the item is = 0; return, and elseif is = 1; return?

Comment: Mean, I didn't understood?

Comment: How can i specify if the item value is "0" do this, and if it is "1" do this ...?

Comment: Here newValue will give you the selected value. So, you can check which item is selected.

Comment: I dont know yet, if i have to check if the preference has changed should i write somerhing like if(newValue  == preference){}?

Comment: Not preference, compare it with the String.

Comment: Yea which string? I have to put a stringe var?

Comment: Not a string variable, Suppose the array contains items like `Classic,New` and it displays in the list preference. So, compare the new value with these items like `newValue.equals("Classic")`

Comment: It doesnt do anything, nothing change (i am working in preference activity)

Comment: Mean, the condition is not specifing or what?

Comment: i don't know i putted if (newValue.equals("dark")){
                 //do this...
             }
             else if (newValue.equals("green")){ //do this else
                }

Comment: Here as per you array, you need to check with 0,1 as the theme_values, its returning 0 & 1. So check it for

Comment: @JonathanI Here as per you array, you need to check with 0,1 as the theme_values, its returning 0 & 1. So check for it.